# How can I set a seed for random array creation in dask?

Tags: python, dask

In dask we can create a random array for example like this.

```py
import dask.array as da

rand = da.random.random((100, 100))
```

For reproducibility I would like to set a random seed, such that `rand` will always have the same content. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `da.random.RandomState` initialized with a specific seed value:

```py
import dask.array as da

# multiple iterations yield the same answer
for _ in range(3):
    state = da.random.RandomState(1234)
    y = state.random(size=(10,1), chunks=(2,2))
    print(y.sum().compute())
```