How to replicate results from numpy.random in Dask
How can I make the results of a numpy random replicable using Dask or joblib Parallel if I can't with Dask?
The get_random function is more complex and manipulates pandas.Dataframe objects.
rng = numpy.random.RandomState(123)
seeds = rng.randint(0, 2**31 - 1, size=10)

def get_random(seed):
    in_rng = numpy.random.RandomState(seed)
    return in_rng.randint(0, 100)

delayed_results = []
for seed in seeds:
       result = dask.delayed(getRandom)(seed)
       delayed_results.append(result)

results = dask.compute(*delayed_results)


Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75455225/10693596

Does this answer your question? How can I set a seed for random array creation in dask?

Already tried that, no success...
